# Why doesn't the length of the string go beyond 16 characters when using .replace operator?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stdstring

I am trying to replace a character '.' in my a string with "[.]", using .replace function as you can see in the code below. However, the string doesn't go beyond 16 characters. On the other hand, by using .insert function, there is no limit for the length of the string. Is there any explanation for this behavior? Thanks

I used .insert function instead.

```
newString = "255.100.50.0";
int len = newString.length(), i =0;
while(i < len){if(newString[i] == '.'){
    newString.replace(i,1, "[.]");
    len = newString.length();
    }
    i += 3;
}
cout << newString << endl;
```

Comment: I think this might be a good time for you to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Use a debugger to step through the program line by line and see if it works as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You increment `i` by 3 whether or not the current character is a period. You only ever look at every third position, and simply skip over and miss some periods, those that happen to be in a position not divisible by 3.

Comment: That's true! I didn't have to increment i in the other method, that is why this problem doesn't occur. Thank you